# How to use Fuzzy Search in MongoDB Atlas Serverless Cluster ($search Alternative for Serverless)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, serverless, mongodb-atlas

I currently use $search to fuzzy match results when finding documents by a string. However, I want to upgrade to server less. Since server less does not allow $search, I need an alternative.

I found this plugin, but the docs do not mention if it works with server less, or if it can be used with other queries: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fuzzy-searching.

How can I use a $search imitation with a server less cluster in MongoDB Atlas?